# Como não ter Warning se eu deixar vazio na formula multiplicação de desconto?

Tags: php, divisão

Como não ter o `Warning: Division by zero in` se eu escolher mesmo colocar zero.  Quero ter a opção de deixar o preço vazio, mas se deixo vazio, ele multiplica como está na formula do desconto e dá erro. Tem como colocar não mostrar esta `div` caso o `deal_price` e `deal_sale_price` estejam vazios ou 0?

```
<ul class="deal-single-value">
    <?php
      $deal_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'deal_price', true);
      $deal_sale_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'deal_sale_price', true);
    ?>

    <li>
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Preço Antigo', 'site' ) ?></p>
        <?php echo site_format_price_number( $deal_price ) ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Desconto de', 'site' ) ?></p>
        <?php echo round( 100 - ( $deal_sale_price / $deal_price ) * 100 ).'%'; ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Você economizou', 'site' ) ?></p>
        <?php echo format_price_number( $deal_price - $deal_sale_price ) ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta colocar um `if` antes de fazer o calculo:

```
<ul class="deal-single-value">
<?php
  $deal_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'deal_price', true);
  $deal_sale_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'deal_sale_price', true);
?>

<li>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Preço Antigo', 'site' ) ?></p>
    <?php echo site_format_price_number( $deal_price ) ?>
</li>

<?php if(!empty($deal_sale_price) && !empty($deal_price)):?>
<li>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Desconto de', 'site' ) ?></p>
    <?php echo round( 100 - ( $deal_sale_price / $deal_price ) * 100 ).'%'; ?>
</li>
<?php endif;?>

<li>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Você economizou', 'site' ) ?></p>
    <?php echo format_price_number( $deal_price - $deal_sale_price ) ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Kenny. Deu certo

Comment: Disponha Peri, considere marcar a resposta como correta para que outras pessoas também possam usufruir da referência! =)

Answer (score 0):

O divisor não pode ser zero pois nenhum número é divisível por zero.

Veja um exemplo de como pode resolver aplicando uma condicional ternária.

```
<?php echo round( 100 - ($deal_price > 0?($deal_sale_price / $deal_price):0) * 100 ).'%'; ?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Daniel. Deu certo aqui